# Can you oath more than one ship?

Tags: azur-lane

Is it possible to oath more than one ship in Azur Lane?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it is possible.** Oaths in Azur Lane are not monogamous.

However, you will need an oath ring for each one and must get each of them to 100 affection points.

Comment: This Q and A, despite being possibly useful, is not very well explained. Could you elaborate a little further?